# A working example for neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am seeking a quick and complete step by step guide that can:

- provide a data set
- show how to  import the data set in the local web service (aka neo4j browser)
- do some queries to show the main features of neo4j

Notes: I tried some tutorials but were not complete or give some failing commands.
Better if a social graph database, better if CSV, but any is ok

Thanks

Comment: You can use the built-in guide: just click on the "Northwind graph" Which has everything you asked for. See also: http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Neo4j GraphGist project: http://graphgist.neo4j.com/#!/gists

There are many examples that showcase many different features of Neo4j (including data import).

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should checkout [GraphAcademy.](http://neo4j.com/graphacademy/)

There are 2 interactive courses:

- [For beginners](http://neo4j.com/graphacademy/online-course/) - it will gently guide you into Neo4j world (with practical examples)
- [Advanced](http://neo4j.com/graphacademy/online-course-prod/) - it contains more advanced topics (i.e. how to configure Neo4j for production envrionment).

---

Also there is tutorial in Neo4j itself. Start Neo4j locally and navigate to your browser (typicall to http://localhost:7474). If this is fresh start - you will be offered to go through introduction.

You can bring up tutorial manually by typing `:play`.

[image]

Just go with "Learn about Neo4j" option here.

Good luck, have fun!

Comment: Thanks, may you suggest a particular example among them that works for sure in your experience? thanks

Comment: I think all those resources worth to checkout. First of all - course for beginners. It gives really good overview. Then - tutorial in database itself. And then - advanced course. And of course - it always will be better if you have real world problem to solve, for training purposes.